# Kubernetes CronJob - Skip job if previous is still running AND wait for the next schedule time

Tags: cron, kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I have scheduled the K8s cron to run every 30 mins.

If the current job is still running and the next cron schedule has reached it shouldn't create a new job but rather wait for the next schedule.

And repeat the same process if the previous job is still in Running state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent a Cronjob execution in Kubernetes if there is already a job running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614715/how-to-prevent-a-cronjob-execution-in-kubernetes-if-there-is-already-a-job-runni)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

set the following property to Forbid in CronJob yaml

```
.spec.concurrencyPolicy
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#concurrency-policy

Answer (score 8):

`spec.concurrencyPolicy: Forbid` will hold off starting a second job if there is still an old one running. However that job will be queued to start immediately after the old job finishes.

To skip running a new job entirely and instead wait until the next scheduled time, set `.spec.startingDeadlineSeconds` to be smaller than the cronjob interval (but larger than the max expected startup time of the job).

If you're running a job every 30 minutes and know the job will never take more than one minute to start, set `.spec.startingDeadlineSeconds: 60`